# Is Toontown canon?

Tags: disney, looney-tunes, who-framed-roger-rabbit

In the movie *Who framed Roger Rabbit*, all cartoon characters working on Hollywood reside in a cartoonish "kind of physical place" (described [here as a pocket dimension](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/Toon)) called Toontown. This includes Disney characters as well as [Looney Tunes, MGM's Droopy and even Betty Boop, Felix the Cat and Woody Woodpecker](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_cameos_in_Who_Framed_Roger_Rabbit).

I doubt that something like Toontown would happen again on screen, but at least on Disney parks, [the place seems to be recognized](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/Toontown), with the obvious omissions in order to avoid copyright infringement, **so I wonder if this place has ever been mentioned again either by Disney or Looney Tunes**, implying that its existence could have slipped into any of their canons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither Disney nor Warner Brothers have referred to ToonTown as a physical place somehow connected to the human world in any of their cartoons since Roger Rabbit. But both have done cartoons where cartoons and "real" humans interact.

Warner Brothers had done a cartoon in the 40s where Daffy and Porky were portrayed as regular employees at Warner Brothers, and Daffy convinced Porky to ask their boss Leon Schlesinger for more money. Both done a number of cartoons where the characters meet (animated) versions of movie stars

A thinly disguised version of Roger Rabbit appeared at the beginning of an audition-themed episode of Tiny Toon Adventures, voiced by Steven Spielberg.

The trademark of Toontown was registered by Disney in 1991. I'm betting that Disney's version of ToonTown is not technically (legally) connected to the city from Roger Rabbit. I suspect the name was never trademarked, (or if it was, it lapsed some time after the film was released) ad Disney snapped it up.  Disney has used the name on both the physical park attraction and the online game Toontown Online.